# Video size getting change on video upload from gallery using UIImagePickerController iOS?

Tags: ios, video, camera, avfoundation

Recorded video from system device camera. Then picking recorded video from gallery using UIImagePickerController. Actual recorded video frame size is (720(w), 1280(h)). that means full screen video with portrait mode. Once I upload video using image picker, getting video size as (1280(w), 720(h)). 
I am finding video size using below code

```
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] lastObject];
    CGSize nSize = [videoTrack naturalSize];
```

How to check original video from gallery with out size changes?

Answer (score 0):

The upload is unrelated. Video rotation is handled by adding a flag the the video metadata. Whatever you are using to read the resolution after the upload is not checking for that flag.

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you send sample code for how to add flag with metadata?

Comment: The flag is already there, you need to read it, not write it.

Comment: Majorly it's not an orientation issue. It's video resolution issue. Portrait video converting or something else is going on on upload. As per my knowledge If I record video with iPhone 5 system device, i will get a video with 640×1136 resolution. Once I upload same video to app, i am getting 1136x640 resolution. I couldn't get exact issue behind this.